# How to make sql selecting loop (simple recursive query)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table, where I have columns NEW_VERSION and OLD_VERSION
OLD_VERSION also has it's older version.
I need to make a query, which will be selecting the whole history of versions

For example:
Table versions_table:

```
OLD_VERSION | NEW_VERSION
10.333        11.111
38.888        39.999
37.777        38.888
9.222         10.333
8.111         9.222
7.999         8.111
36.666        37.777 
35.555        36.666
```

We know only newest version "11.111". 
For query `SELECT * FROM versions_table WHERE NEW_VERSION = 11.111 ...`
Output should be:

```
OLD_VERSION | NEW_VERSION
    10.333        11.111
    9.222         10.333
    8.111         9.222
    7.999         8.111
```

Could you please advise me, what is the suitable approach for this?

Thank you!

Comment: Is that sample table data, or the expected result? We need both! Also show us your current query attempt!

Comment: Expected output is must here..One can help better if he knows whats the expected output

Comment: Can't you just write `SELECT * FROM versions_table WHERE NEW_VERSION <= 11.111 ...`

Comment: @Jens No, because there may be other lower versions which I don't need. In output should be strict history

Comment: How do you determine if there's an older version you don't need? OLD_VERSION & NEW_VERSION don't match up?

Comment: @Jens Yes, exactly. Let's assume that this table stores versions of different applications. But we don't have any identifier for this applications in versions_table, only OLD_VERSION & NEW_VERSION

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a (simple) recursive query:

```
select *
from versions
start with new_version = '11.111'
connect by prior old_version = new_version;
```

Comment: Thank you, it is what I need.